# Flutter layout widgets unable to set as need

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am try to set card like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLYqV.png) image.i have use within Row Expanded and getting [is](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14tiwiTRtt8z5H53eWRRmsFRodirgpZOP) out put here is my code

```
return Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70, width: 1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      child: new InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "${_userDetails[index].manifiest}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 40.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          IconButton(
                                            icon: new Icon(
                                              Icons.edit,
                                            ),
                                            iconSize: 30,
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              int id =
                                                  userData[index]['id'];

                                              Navigator.push(
                                                  context,
                                                  MaterialPageRoute(

                                                      ));
                                            },
                                          ),
                                          IconButton(
                                            icon: new Icon(
                                              Icons.cancel,
                                            ),
                                            iconSize: 30,
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Utils.isConnected()
                                                  .then((intenet) {
                                                if (intenet != null &&
                                                    intenet) {
                                                  // Internet Present Case
                                                  showAlertDialogTwo(
                                                      context,
                                                      "Are Sure You Want To Delete?",
                                                      index);
                                                } else {
                                                  Utils.alertDialog(
                                                      context,
                                                      'Make Sure Connected with Internet',
                                                      "");
                                                }
                                                // No-Internet Case
                                              });
                                            },
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                          "${_userDetails[index].fromBranch} ",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black45,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16.0)),
                                      Icon(Icons.compare_arrows,
                                          color: Colors.black54),
                                      Text(
                                          " ${_userDetails[index].toBranch}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black45,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16.0)),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                      ),
                                  Text("${_userDetails[index].date}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black45,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  new Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5)),
                                  Text("${_userDetails[index].time}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black45,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  new Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 30.0,
                                  ))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[

                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("Consignment"
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("${_userDetails[index].totalConsignments}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("PCs ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("${_userDetails[index].totalPcs}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  new Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 30.0,
                                      ))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("Weight ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("${_userDetails[index].totalWeight}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  ),

                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("By",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                                  ),

                                  Expanded(
                                    child:Text("${_userDetails[index].enteredBy}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                  ),
                                  new Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 30.0,
                                      ))
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10, top: 10, right: 10),
                    );
```

also i have use Flexible in Row i am getting [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KKlzC4ZkxCkEKOoAeCtvFtt5mpQTTPZF/view?usp=sharing) type of output  and here is my Flexible code

```
 Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Text("Consignmens",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                                    flex: 3,
                                  ),
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                          "${_userDetails[index].totalConsignments}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black45,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 12.0)),
                                    ),
                                    flex: 2,
                                  ),
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Center(
                                      child: Text("PCs ",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16.0)),
                                    ),
                                    flex: 2,
                                  ),
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Text(
                                        "${_userDetails[index].totalPcs}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                    flex: 2,
                                  ),
                                  new Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 30.0,
                                  ))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: Text("Weight",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 16.0)),
                                    flex: 3,
                                  ),
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                          "${_userDetails[index].totalWeight}",

                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black45,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 12.0)),
                                    ),
                                    flex: 2,
                                  ),
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Center(
                                      child: Text("By",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black54,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16.0)),
                                    ),
                                    flex: 2,
                                  ),
                                  new Flexible(
                                    child: new Text(
                                        "${_userDetails[index].enteredBy}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12.0)),
                                    flex: 2,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
```

Please help me i am new to flutter. 
if any correction in this code required  also tell me. 
Thank You in advance

Comment: All links to screenshots are same. Please update the links.

Comment: @KumarBibek i am updating links please see

Comment: you can use `flex` property in `Expanded` widget also.